# Cannot validate argument on parameter

Tags: powershell, properties

To create a pool I am trying to select 4 disks out of 6.

I can get the list of UniqueIds as below:

```
PS C:\> Get-PhysicalDisk|? Canpool|ft UniqueId

UniqueId
--------
{3b34bfc1-1022-11e9-9df0-806e6f6e6963}
{3b34bfc3-1022-11e9-9df0-806e6f6e6963}
{3b34bfc5-1022-11e9-9df0-806e6f6e6963}
{3b34bfc7-1022-11e9-9df0-806e6f6e6963}
{3b34bfc9-1022-11e9-9df0-806e6f6e6963}
{3b34bfcb-1022-11e9-9df0-806e6f6e6963}
```

I can also choose the first four:

```
PS C:\> Get-PhysicalDisk |? CanPool|? HealthStatus| select -first 4

FriendlyName  SerialNumber CanPool OperationalStatus HealthStatus Usage       Size
------------  ------------ ------- ----------------- ------------ -----       ----
VBOX HARDDISK              True    OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 5 GB
VBOX HARDDISK              True    OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 5 GB
VBOX HARDDISK              True    OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 5 GB
VBOX HARDDISK              True    OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 5 GB
```

What I want to achieve is to select the disks I want, not the first 4 or all, but let's say disk numbers 1, 2, 4, 6 or UnıqueId starting with 3b34bfc1, 3b34bfc3, 3b34bfc7, 3b34bfcb.

Comment: If you store this in a variable you should just be able to select them like you would with an array: `$test = (Get-PhysicalDisk|? Canpool|ft UniqueId); $test[1,2,4,6];`

Comment: Or you could just use `(Get-PhysicalDisk|? Canpool|ft UniqueId)[1,2,4,6]`

Comment: Is there a particular property you're looking for? e.g. only SSDs? Or are you really just looking for various specific disks on a single system? If you're really only basing this off of the UniqueId then you won't be able to do much better than simply copy and paste the UniqueIds into a `Where-Object {($_.UniqueId -eq "3b34bfc1") -or ($_.UniqueId -eq "3b34bfc3") -or ...}` which doesn't do much for you in the way of automation.

Comment: @Owain Esau unfortunately got an error here

PS C:\Users\Administrator> (Get-PhysicalDisk|? CanPool|ft UniqueId)[1,2,4,6]
out-lineoutput : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [out-lineoutput], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutLineOutputCommand

Comment: @OwainEsau 
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $test=(Get-PhysicalDisk|? CanPool|ft UniqueId)
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $test[1,2,4,6]
out-lineoutput : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [out-lineoutput], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutLineOutputCommand

Comment: @DustyVargas  unfortunately it also did not work.
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-PhysicalDisk -CanPool $True | Where-Object {$_.UniqueId -eq "f11960e9-1183-11e9-9df1-806e
6f6e6963"} -or {$_.UniqueId -eq "f11960ea-1183-11e9-9df1-806e6f6e6963"}
Where-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'or'.
At line:1 char:105
+ ...  {$_.UniqueId -eq "f11960e9-1183-11e9-9df1-806e6f6e6963"} -or {$_.Uni ...
+                                                               ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException

Comment: You need to wrap your block in braces, and each condition in parentheses e.g. {($_.Property -eq "value") -or ($_.Property -eq "value2") ...}

Comment: Here I found the solution :
`PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-PhysicalDisk|? Canpool|ft UniqueId

{78f3d471-15cb-11e9-9df3-806e6f6e6963}
{78f3d472-}
{78f3d473-}
{78f3d474-}
{78f3d475-}
{78f3d476-}

PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-PhysicalDisk|? Canpool|? {"{78f3d471};{78f3d472}".Contains($_.UniqueId)}

FriendlyName  SerialNumber CanPool OperationalStatus HealthStatus Usage       Size

VBOX HARDDISK              True    OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 5 GB
VBOX HARDDISK              True    OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 5 GB
`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$idFilter = '3b34bfc1', '3b34bfc3', '3b34bfc7', '3b34bfcb'
Get-PhysicalDisk -CanPool $true -HealthStatus 'Healthy' | 
     Where-Object { $idFilter -contains (($_.UniqueId).Substring(1, 8)) } | 
     Select -First 4
```

Using your examples, this would return:

> ```
> UniqueId                               FriendlyName  SerialNumber CanPool OperationalStatus HealthStatus Usage       Size
> --------                               ------------  ------------ ------- ----------------- ------------ -----       ----
> {3b34bfc1-1022-11e9-9df0-806e6f6e6963} VBOX HARDDISK              True    OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 5 GB
> {3b34bfc3-1022-11e9-9df0-806e6f6e6963} VBOX HARDDISK              True    OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 5 GB
> {3b34bfc7-1022-11e9-9df0-806e6f6e6963} VBOX HARDDISK              True    OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 5 GB
> {3b34bfcb-1022-11e9-9df0-806e6f6e6963} VBOX HARDDISK              True    OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 5 GB
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately it returns empty
        

PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-PhysicalDisk | Where-Object {($_.CanPool) -and $_.HealthStatus -eq 'Healthy'} | Where-Object { $idFilter -contains (($_.UniqueId).Substring(1, 8)) } |Select -First 4 | Format-Table -AutoSize

Comment: @CanBuyukburc I've edited the code and changed the filtering on the `CanPool` property syntax. Can you try this?

Comment: Unfortunately it came empty again. I also tried some versions but comes empty.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it :

```
    PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-PhysicalDisk|? Canpool|ft UniqueId

    UniqueId
    --------
    {78f3d471-15cb-11e9-9df3-806e6f6e6963}
    {78f3d472-15cb-11e9-9df3-806e6f6e6963}
    {78f3d473-15cb-11e9-9df3-806e6f6e6963}
    {78f3d474-15cb-11e9-9df3-806e6f6e6963}
    {78f3d475-15cb-11e9-9df3-806e6f6e6963}
    {78f3d476-15cb-11e9-9df3-806e6f6e6963}


    PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-PhysicalDisk|? Canpool|? {"{78f3d471-15cb-11e9-        9df3-806e6f6e6963};{78f3d472-15cb-11e9-9df
    3-806e6f6e6963}".Contains($_.UniqueId)}

    FriendlyName  SerialNumber CanPool OperationalStatus HealthStatus Usage       Size
    ------------  ------------ ------- ----------------- ------------ -----       ----
    VBOX HARDDISK              True    OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 5 GB
    VBOX HARDDISK              True    OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 5 GB
```